# OkHTTP3 in Android

Tags: java, android

i use okhttp3 in android studio 2.2.3 on a simple project.
my project run on emulator (nexus 5 android 7 API 24) without any problem
but in my phones (lg k10 android 6 API 23) and (huawei honor 4x API 19)
crashed and has stopped.
i use okhttp3 package 
   com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1
in my project
my module:app is->

(compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "android.hrsh.okhttpv2"
   minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25)

my code is:

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.imodares.ir/json-url/imodares-json.html")
            .build();
    Callback callback = new Callback() {...}
  try {
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);

    }
    catch (Exception e ){label.setText(e.getMessage());}
```

i test my code with

```
 client.newCall(request).execute();
```

but i get same result 
please guide me
thanks

Comment: Post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you test with the debug apk on your emulator and the release one on your phone? If it is, proguard might be the problem.

Comment: i use run (shift+f10) button in android studio

Comment: I think I should consider a setting in my project so that my problem can be resolved. Thanks if you can offer a few solutions

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and found out I should use the following code:

```
  class ReadFromNet extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String s;
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            InputStream jsonStream=getStreamFromURL("http://www.imodares.ir/json-url/imodares-json.html","GET");
            s=streamToString(jsonStream);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            setViewData(s);
        }

    }
    ReadFromNet rj=new ReadFromNet();
    rj.execute();
```

But I still did not understand the reason for the previous error message in the method of using okhttp.